# iphone : customize the calendar pick up date

Tags: iphone, calendar

My client would like that the user could pick up a date in an iphone app.

He wants that all the days of the month appear. Moreover he would like to switch to the next or previous month. How would it possible to do that ?

Moreover he would like that in the calendar some days of the month (for ex. the 1rst, the 9th and the 15th) appear in a different color.

If it's possible, how could this be done ?

Thank you in advance for your help

Fabio

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there isn't a calendar object exposed in the 3.x iPhone SDK.

You can however implement your own.  One way would be to implement your own UIView object and handle the painting and reaction to touching manually.  Another way would be to implement a calendar as an HTML page and either create a full web application or embed a UIWebView.

http://dblog.com.au/iphone-development/iphone-sdk-tutorial-build-your-very-own-web-browser/